# Load an image in modal window with jquery, dom mutation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have an online magazine in pageflip style. Each page should be clickable and show me an image in a high resolution (modal window). I'm using a pageflip.js for this.

But when i load the website i can click only the first 4 pages. Thats because the next pages are loaded dynamicaly and the DOM changes.
How can i observe a live dom changing ?

the site is online: http://textileworld.esy.es/book.php

The function `$('.show-modal').on('click', function())` is not working for the live dom changing.

i Open the modal window with this code:

```
$('.show-modal').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var highres = null;
                highres = $(this).parent().prev().attr('data-highres');
                $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
                $('#modal-image').attr('src', highres);
             });
```

the page-images are loaded in php:

```
'<img id="img" data-highres="'.$imageHighResolution.'" src="'.$image.'" usemap="#image'.$i.'"/>',
                    '<map name="image'.$i.'">',
                    '<area class="show-modal" shape="rect" coords="35,1,725,1094" alt="clickable">',
                    '</map>';
```

and the html for the modal window:

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <!-- Close button -->
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <img class="modal-content" id="modal-image">
        <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the 3 parameter version of `.on()` which creates a delegated event

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

`$(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function())`

To improve performance bind the event delegation to the nearest parent, so the event doesn't need to bubble to the document element to be executed.

Comment: That solved my problem but now im getting (when i click on a new page) for few second an old image than it load the correct one.

Comment: @GregOstry I tested it with different browsers. Edge (IE) and FireFox gave me the same bug, but Chrome, Safari and Opera worked as expected. After the user closes the modal remove the img tag or the source tag.

Comment: // close modal content (x button)
`$('span').on('click', function(){
 $('.modal').css('display', 'none');
 highres = null;
});`  I added highres=null; but this didn't solve my problem

Comment: @GregOstry You only set a variable to null. You have to make a DOM manipulation at least. eg. `$('#modal-image').attr('src', '');`